# How to make my pricing table appear when clicking a button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I'm building a website and I want to make a fancy animation for my pricing tables where they appear when you click their name. You can see the website [here](https://rhumbert1.github.io/devis-ms/).

I've already tried [this code](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp) from W3 Schools on how to make an accordion and wrapping the "panel" class around my pricing table but it didn't worked out for me, do you have any suggestions ? Below is the code of my pricing table and it's styling. For your information on the wbesite all the pricing boxes uses the same code.

```css
.first-titre-table {
  color: black;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

.titre-table {
  margin-top: 50%;
  color: black;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700);

.snip1404 {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  left: 20%;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 7%;
  display: block;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.snip1404 img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.snip1404 .plan {
  margin: 6px;
  margin-top: 7px;
  width: 25%;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 5px solid #730000;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
  background-color: #b30000;
}

.snip1404 .plan:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.snip1404 * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
}

.snip1404 header {
  background-color: #b30000;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.snip1404 .plan-title {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px 20px 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
}

.snip1404 .plan-title::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 40px 300px 0 0;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) transparent transparent;
}

.snip1404 .plan-cost {
  padding: 40px 20px 10px;
  text-align: right;
}

.snip1404 .plan-price {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 3em;
}

.snip1404 .plan-type {
  opacity: 0.8;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.snip1404 .plan-features {
  padding: 0 0 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  list-style: outside none none;
  text-align: center;
}

.snip1404 .plan-features li {
  padding: 8px 5%;
}

.snip1404 .plan-features i {
  margin-right: 8px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.snip1404 .plan-select {
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.snip1404 .plan-select a {
  background-color: #700000;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  font-weight: 600;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.snip1404 .plan-select a:hover {
  background-color: #ff4d4d;
}

.text-garantie {
  font-size: 17px;
  display: inline;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 7px #ddd;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .snip1404 .plan {
    width: 50%;
  }
  
  .snip1404 .plan-title,
  .snip1404 .plan-select a {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  
  .snip1404 .plan-select,
  .snip1404 .plan-featured .plan-select {
    padding: 20px;
  }
  
  .snip1404 .plan-featured {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 440px) {
  .snip1404 .plan {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .snip1404 .plan-non-featured {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .snip1404 .plan-featured {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="snip1404">
  <h2 class="first-titre-table">
    Contrats Chaudière Gaz
  </h2>
  <div class="plan">
    <header>
      <h4 class="plan-title">
        Contrat 1 an
      </h4>
      <div class="plan-cost">
        <span class="plan-price">
          188€
        </span>
        <span class="plan-type">
          /an
        </span>
      </div>
    </header>
    <ul class="plan-features">
      <li>
        1 intervention/an
      </li>
      <li style="margin-bottom:63%;">
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="plan-select">
      <a href="">
        Choisir
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to keep this site as framework free as possible because I don't know how it's gonna behave when I will try to host it on my company's servers so please consider this before answering, thanks !

Comment: I'm sorry what exactly are you looking for. I mean what is the issue?

Comment: well I'm just asking how to do it, not a super specific problem here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.first-titre-table').click(function(){
  $(this).next('.plan').slideToggle()
})
```

If I've understood you, this jQuery will do what you want.
Of course, you need to hide it first.

```
.plan{
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Well this kinda works but only for the first box of each table, like the "Contrat 1 an" box is working fine but the other ones are not moving

Comment: $('.first-titre-table').click(function(){
  $(this).siblings('.plan').slideToggle()
})

Comment: this is my pleasure!

Answer (score 0):

I tried [this code](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp) from W3 Schools. Is this what you want?

Your website have js error and stop so other js can't execute. You need to fixed it by yourself.

[image]

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
```

```css
.first-titre-table {
  color: black;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

.titre-table {
  margin-top: 50%;
  color: black;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700);

.snip1404 {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  left: 20%;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 7%;
  display: block;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.snip1404 img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.snip1404 .plan {
  margin: 6px;
  margin-top: 7px;
  width: 25%;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 5px solid #730000;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
  background-color: #b30000;
}

.snip1404 .plan:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.snip1404 * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
}

.snip1404 header {
  background-color: #b30000;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.snip1404 .plan-title {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px 20px 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
}

.snip1404 .plan-title::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 40px 300px 0 0;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) transparent transparent;
}

.snip1404 .plan-cost {
  padding: 40px 20px 10px;
  text-align: right;
}

.snip1404 .plan-price {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 3em;
}

.snip1404 .plan-type {
  opacity: 0.8;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.snip1404 .plan-features {
  padding: 0 0 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  list-style: outside none none;
  text-align: center;
}

.snip1404 .plan-features li {
  padding: 8px 5%;
}

.snip1404 .plan-features i {
  margin-right: 8px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.snip1404 .plan-select {
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.snip1404 .plan-select a {
  background-color: #700000;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  font-weight: 600;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.snip1404 .plan-select a:hover {
  background-color: #ff4d4d;
}

.text-garantie {
  font-size: 17px;
  display: inline;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 7px #ddd;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .snip1404 .plan {
    width: 50%;
  }
  
  .snip1404 .plan-title,
  .snip1404 .plan-select a {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  
  .snip1404 .plan-select,
  .snip1404 .plan-featured .plan-select {
    padding: 20px;
  }
  
  .snip1404 .plan-featured {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 440px) {
  .snip1404 .plan {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .snip1404 .plan-non-featured {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .snip1404 .plan-featured {
    width: 100%;
  }
}


/* Style the buttons that are used to open and close the accordion panel */
.accordion {
  transition: 0.4s;
}

/* Add a background color to the button if it is clicked on (add the .active class with JS), and when you move the mouse over it (hover) */
.active, .accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the accordion panel. Note: hidden by default */
.panel {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="snip1404">
  <h2 class="first-titre-table accordion">
    Contrats Chaudière Gaz
  </h2>
  <div class="plan panel">
    <header>
      <h4 class="plan-title">
        Contrat 1 an
      </h4>
      <div class="plan-cost">
        <span class="plan-price">
          188€
        </span>
        <span class="plan-type">
          /an
        </span>
      </div>
    </header>
    <ul class="plan-features">
      <li>
        1 intervention/an
      </li>
      <li style="margin-bottom:63%;">
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="plan-select">
      <a href="">
        Choisir
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: OP could have forgotten to use the JS included in tutorial

Comment: nope I have the js on my website but it didn't worked

Comment: yeah it's almost what I want, is there a way of removing the little red bar at the top of the pricing table ? like totaly hidden ?

Comment: The red bar is your border.

Comment: @yip102011 ok I deleted the border but i can't click the table's title in order the make the table appear, any idea why ? PS: I updated the website so you can see where it's stuck

Comment: @yip102011 js errors are fixed but still doesn't open up, site's updated

Comment: I get this error in my console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'maxHeight' of undefined
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (main.js:8)
Every time I click the tables title